# "In back of'' vs. "back of" vs. the spatial sense of "behind" in AmE

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, formality, colloquialisms

What's the difference to these expressions, as in "The little girl was hiding in back of the tree" vs. "The little girl was hiding back of the tree" vs. "The little girl was hiding behind the tree"?

In addition, do "in back of" and "back of" have any currency in AE today? Plus, are these idioms safe to use for all proses, even the most formal one?

Comment: Rather equal.  Both are used currently.

Comment: They don't mean quite the same thing, though. Not everything has a back. See [Fillmore's Deixis Lecture](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) no. 2, [on "Space"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Comment: @David: It's stretching things a bit to say they're "equal". Relatively speaking, dialectal *in back of X* has [virtually no currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hiding+in+back+of%2Chiding+behind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chiding%20in%20back%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chiding%20behind%3B%2Cc0) compared to ***behind** X*.

Comment: There's a usage note given in RHK Webster's:  usage: Although some object to their use, the phrases 'in back of' and the shorter - and much older - 'back of' with the meaning “behind” are fully established as standard in American English: 'They played (in) back of the house.' Both phrases occur in all types of speech and writing, though 'behind' may be easily substituted if desired.>> This implies that even this purely locative usage has been bleached of some of its original ('there must be a back involved') constraints.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I actually hesitated in adding "back of" to the OP because I thought it was sort of "less formal" than "in back of".

Comment: We rarely use either on this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: The tree doesn't have a *"back"*, so you have to say she has was hiding *"behind"* the tree. The preposition *"in back of"* always means absolute position, while *"behind"* can either mean absolute or relative position. In other words, if the little girl was on the left side of a car, and I was on the right side, I could say that I couldn't see her because she was *behind* the car. But she wouldn't be *in back of* the car.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree re: trees.  But why not in back of the car?  It would generally be stationary at that time, but something could be in back of the car.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Perhaps I was a bit ... rash in my statement.  If an item has a back, they can be used fairly interchangeably.

Comment: @Peter There are over 4 000 000 hits for a Google search for ["in back of the tree"](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=%22in+back+of+the+tree%22). Over 7 000 000 for  "in back of the box". A few less, admittedly, for "in back of the Moon". Both 'behind' and 'in back of' are deictic; the reference may well be the observer rather than an intrinsic frontness.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't agree re: trees. This in fact is all a matter of spatial relativity and position. A tree doesn't have a "back", but neither does a car or a house actually. If I carve a drawing into a tree and define the part of the tree where the drawing lies as the "back", then the tree has a "back" just like a car and a house do.

Comment: @PeterShor Also, both "in back of" and "back of", unlike "in front of", have seemingly some deeply entrenched idiomacy to them as far as AmE goes.

Comment: As Fillmore points out, where the "back" of the tree is depends on where the observer is with relation to the tree. But that's strictly relative to one situation, because trees don't have a back, whereas _house_ often does. In that case, _behind the house_ means out of the observer's sight on the other side of the house, while _in back of the house_ is more likely to refer to the absolute "back" part of the house, regardless of the observer's position. So they could be different in the right context.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's correctly said. I had not encompassed that aspect of the preposition "behind".

Comment: "In back of the car" can be interpreted to mean behind the rear bumper OR if the car has its side facing the viewer and the hider is ducked down along the opposite side, it can be said that the hider is also "in back of the car"...or "behind the car".

Comment: As a non AE observer of this discussion I find it difficult to see how anything behind a car could be beside it. A car clearly does have a front, a back, and two sides.

Comment: ... 'In back of the flying saucer' might work better.

Comment: @PeterShor I can't help but think there's a lot more to "in back of" than a matter of absolute position with respect to things that don't have a "back" like trees and doors. To my ear, saying "the girl is sitting crouched right in back of the door (or tree)" or "the girl is sitting crouched right behind the door (or tree)" means just about the same, i.e. she is sitting crouched right by the other side of the door (or tree) from where the observer is standing, and are as such both correct options. However, I quite agree with you on things that have a "back" like cars and houses.

Comment: I agree with you about *"in back of the door"*. So I'll modify my position: *behind* is much more likely to be relative than *"in back of"*.

Comment: @andy256: [Here](http://frankfharrisonmedia.blogspot.com/2009/09/vw-polo-small-but-tough.html) is a blog post talking about police hiding behind a VW when it is quite clear from the picture that they are hiding on one side of it.

Comment: @PeterShor How about in the context of a person sitting in back of another as in a theatre, or in a "romantic" context involving two lovers? Can "in back of" and "behind" be used just about interchangeably for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a formal answer to this question -- As you can see from comments above, there is disagreement amongst native speakers on this matter:

For many speakers of AmE, [*in back of*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_back_of) and [*behind*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/behind) are used fairly interchangeably as prepositions.

In general, *behind* represents the relative position to the speaker.  So, if the speaker is standing to one side of a car, the object may be behind the car if it is on the far side of the car.  In other words, it is not necessary for the relative position to be the rear of the object, but that the object be located between the speaker and the subject.

*In back of* can represent this same relationship.

*The confusing part*: if the object has a back or a rear, the relative position does not necessarily dictate the meaning of the preposition.  In other words, if the speaker and the subject are both at the rear of a house, they are both *in back of* or *behind* the house.

If the subject is front of the house, and the speaker is behind the house, *few* would now say the subject is behind the house even if it *is*, relative to the speaker.  This will seem confusing compared to the situation with the car above.  My instinct is that this has more to do with perception than anything else.  The rear of a house is a very distinctive location.  The rear of a car is at best a few feet from its side.

If there is any difference between the two: **to my ear**, *in back of* sounds vaguely colloquial.  I cannot find any data on this, and I doubt this is universal for all speakers of AmE.  An attempt to plot an [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+back+of%2C+behind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20back%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbehind%3B%2Cc0) of *in back of* yields relatively few results, especially when compared to *behind*.

Answer (score 2):

I noted John Muir's phrasing in "My First Visit To The Sierras":

June 10: "...Heard a few peals of thunder from the upper Sierra, and saw firm white bossy cumuli rising back of the pines."

I'm an avid reader of many genres and authors but cannot recall a single instance of the use of "in back of" -presented seriously- before reading Muir, who was not without education and practical knowledge.